# Trying to deploy ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Site on Microsoft Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

This works on my local machine but when I try to deploy to Azure, I get the following error:

I didn't even use code first, I used database first.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a copy of your web.config and a picture of your project/Entity model.

Comment: It seems that you don't publish database to SQL Azure. If it is that case, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025295/asp-net-mvc-how-to-deploy-to-azure-using-entity-framework-model-database-first) to get details steps.